# Get displayed Image after Matrix scale

Tags: android, image, user-interface

I have an `ImageView` with `ScaleType matrix`. below is my ImageView:

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+imageEdit/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:scaleType="matrix" />
```

Now I have have set the source as `image.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);`

till now Everything is fine. But now I would like to move and rotate image inside ImageView so I have set onTouchListner to this ImageView.

I have referred to this [Multi Touch in Android – Translate, Scale, and Rotate](http://judepereira.com/blog/multi-touch-in-android-translate-scale-and-rotate/)

Once Image is scaled and rotated then how to use this Image in another ImageView.

**Alternative:**  if it is not possible then I would like this ImageView to be sized as the displayed Image inside this ImageView with all the changes.

Comment: I think you are doing image processing. If so you have to store edited  copy in same file or as different one. Then load that file in imageview.

Comment: @Paritosh thnx for reply.Yes you are right. I am doing Image processing. but due to my requirements I need what I asked above.

Comment: see set/getImageMatrix()

Comment: @pskink what to do with set/getImageMatrix()

Comment: call getter for first ImageView and setter for second one

Comment: @pskink let me give it a try

Comment: @pskink  Not working!!!

Comment: Too bad its not working!!!